# Use parameters for variable animation

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I'd like to animate my Score-GUI text counting up to a variable value but there are two things in my way:

## 1: How can I animate to a variable instead of a fixed value?

## 2: Why can't I add own properties (like `int`) to my script and animate them?

For #2 I created a property in my script. Yet the editor won't show it in the AddProperty-dialog (as shown below):

[image]

```
public int currentScore = 0;

public int score {
    get { return currentScore; }
    set { this.currentScore += value; }
}
```

**EDIT:** The animator is set up in the most basic way:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, why are you having this problem. It is possible to do both of your question. 1 : Animation have their own value set, depending on the timeline where they will overwrite their own value. Now if you overwrite this in the Script. The time line value is still dominant to changes.
2 : Like I said you can make the script overwrite the Value of the animation but if the TimeLine is still running(The Animation). The Timeline value will still be dominant as it is running consistently.

Comment: So you say it is possible but animating to a value set via script will be disregarded? That would mean it isn't possible.
I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Both Possible, but in this way. 1 if the timeline is running and setting its value it is dominant. Now if there is no current key presented on the Timeline, The Script will be dominant. The best approach you can take is adding an Animator. As Animator Works with your script and your animation. I think you haven't added an Animator, cause normally you would not have this problem in the first place.

Comment: I saw that there is an Animator in your Picture. But not sure how you set it up.

Comment: It only contains one additional State `AddScore` containing the AddScore animation which is supposed to count up the score. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Ok now you have two options based on what you need. You can use trigger or bool. If you use boolean. The AddScore animation will run unless the condition is not met which I think you don't want. Trigger on the other hand will only run once. This is for the properties inside the Animator.

Comment: hmm, I want to set a property in the script, trigger the animation and then just have it count up to any score I set it to within two seconds.

Comment: Ok, that makes your question a lot more sense. I will post an Answer.

Comment: One last confirmation. if you want the Animation to set the Value on the script. You would need Boolean instead of trigger, as you need the animation to continuously run. Is that what you want?

Comment: The animation is supposed to only run when new points are added to the score. Once it reaches the target-score its supposed to not run any further. Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only have 1 Animation. An Animator is irrelevant to the solution. This is tested and working. Now you need to make the Animation a Legacy type to get this working because we are not going to use the Animator.

Click the Animation on the Project -> look at the upper right section of the Inspector view, there is a little button there which will drop down a selection. "Debug" then Check the Legacy.

Set your Animation to whatever you want. I force the WrapMode in the script to be wrap mode once. So it will only play once.

Now in the Animation Component make sure you select the Animation that you want by default or it wont work. Cause we only use anim.Play(); Without parameters meaning, run the default animation that is set.

I created a Text UI and added an Animation that alpha is 0 from the start and at the end point making it 1. You have to do that on your own.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MyScore : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public int currentScore = 0;
public GameObject Myscore; // Drag the GameObject that has the Animation for your score.
public Text myScoreText; //Drag in the Inspector the Text object to reference
public Animation anim;

public int score
{
    get { return currentScore; }
    set { this.currentScore += value; }
}
void Start()
{
    anim = Myscore.GetComponent<Animation>(); // Reference the Animation Component.

    anim.wrapMode = WrapMode.Once; // Legacy animation Set to play once
    AddScore();
}
public void AddScore()
{
    score += 10;
    myScoreText.text = score.ToString();
    anim.Play();
    Debug.Log("Current Score is "+ score);
    Invoke("AddScore", 2);
}




}
```

Good luck.